# Internal Power Error

Tags: windows-10, bsod, power, dump, minidumps

From time to time my 1st attempt to turn on my PC fails (the motherboard manufacturer logo is displayed and then immediately PC shuts down). Every attempt after that is always successful.

Here is the dump file content that was generated during this error. What I can add is that I'm not using the hibernate mode on my Windows 10 and it is turned off in power settings.
What can be the problem and how can I troubleshoot that?

**Dump file:**

```
INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR (a0) The power policy manager experienced a fatal error.  

Arguments:  
Arg1: 000000000000010e, The disk subsystem returned corrupt data while reading from the hibernation file.  
Arg2: 000000000000000a  
Arg3: 000000000000f116, Incorrect checksum  
Arg4: 000000000000723e, Previous disk read's checksum  

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 0xa0_10e_0xa_HIBERSTACK_INIT_FAILED_IMAGE_stornvme.sys  
IMAGE_NAME: stornvme.sys
MODULE_NAME: stornvme  
FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80767ff0000 stornvme
```

Comment: fyi: You may not be using hibernation directly, but implicitly via the Fast Startup feature.

Comment: from what I found online, its mostly a problem with the power supply, either its inadequate for your rig, or it is failing for some reason. (maybe this might not be the issue, coz the dump file reports that its corrupt data while reading from the disk, but anyways...)